# Windows 10 PCs not seeing Linux samba

Tags: linux, windows-10, samba

I have 3x Windows 10 PC's and a 4th PC running Linux Mint 18.  Up until yesterday everything was working fine.  Now the Windows 10 PCs will not see the Linux PC in the Network folder, but can connect to it if the hostname or ip address is manually entered in the address bar.  I have restarted all network devices (router and switch).  Also, the Linux PC will not see the Windows PC's.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Between Windows and Linux Samba, the only common "network discovery" protocol is the NetBIOS-based "computer browsing".

- In Windows, it requires SMBv1 client support to be installed (see [MS instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/detect-enable-disable-smbv1-smbv2-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server)).
- In Samba, it requires the `nmbd` daemon (nmb.service) to be running.
- The 'workgroup' parameter on all systems must match.
- The network must support IPv4; the firewalls must allow UDP/137, UDP/138, probably TCP/139.

Try using `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP` and see if it produces any results.

(Modern Windows systems support WS-Discovery so they can still detect other computers even without NetBIOS.)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue. I can visit linux sharing by ip or host name, but can't see the linux host in file explorer -> network. The solution is to install wsd or wsdd in linux. Tested working in opensuse leap 15.2.

Comment: this should be the accepted and top answer. I am using the wsdd package on all my ubuntu installs from 22.04 to 23.04

Answer (score 0):

Try to find that the network share is connected or not using this command in cmd.

```
net use
```

if connected then delete the network share using

```
net use sharename /delete
```

then logout and login again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all. I went into Windows Features and installed SMBv1 and it instantly did the trick.  I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: You should be aware SMBv1 is extremely vulnerable.  You should upgrade the Linux end so it supports SMBv3.

Answer (score -1):

"Between Windows and Linux Samba, the only common "network discovery" protocol is the NetBIOS-based "computer browsing"

Not anymore, you can implement Web Service Discovery in Linux now.

I fixed this on the server side by using wsdd (a lot easier than updating all the clients).  Pre-made service files are available from the guy's git also - although I had to change the group from nobody to nogroup to get the systemd script to work in Ubuntu.  This is a lot cleaner than using obsolete SMB1 (which has security issues).

https://github.com/christgau/wsdd